# Does the -o-animation vendor prefix exist?

Tags: css, opera, vendor-prefix

I'm trying to find out if I need to include the `-o-animation` vendor prefix in my CSS, but I can't seem to find any resources which indicates it exists, and if it does, what versions of Opera it applies to.

Can anyone offer some suggestions?

Comment: According to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation), they use `-webkit-` straight away. This probably has to do with [Opera moving to webkit recently](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/300-million-users-and-move-to-webkit).

Comment: According to Can I Use (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), the prefix was used in the Opera 12.00 series. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

The -o-animation vendor prefix is no longer required for Opera, unless you need to support old Opera v12.** versions.

Instead, use the -webkit-animation vendor prefix to support newer Opera.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Opera 12.10 release notes](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/unified/1210/), you didn't need the `-o-` vendor prefix from that version on. Adding `-o-` was therefore just needed to support Opera 12.0x versions.